# Can't get a binding from code behind to work for combo box

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, combobox

I'm trying to bind a list to a combo box by adapting [the wisdom of the internet](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/permanenttan/archive/2009/06/21/data-bind-using-only-code-behind.aspx) but it doesn't seem to render the strings I provide. Intellisense says that the combo box has three items in it but they just don't appear on the screen.

```
Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.Source = new List<String> {"aa","bb","cc"};
MyComboBox.SetBinding(ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty, binding);
```

To be sure, I tried the same with the label control using the code below. This one seems to work, so I sense that I'm putting my junk in the wrong hole.

```
Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.Source = "Beep";
MyLabel.SetBinding(Label.ContentProperty, binding);
```

## Edit

Always trying to create a minimal example, which in a few rare occasions may lead to exclusion of crucial details. Here's the XAML code as well.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="MyComboBox"
                  DisplayMemberPath="Canonic"
                  Style="{StaticResource DefaultComboBoxStyle}" />-->
```

Comment: Works for me. Is there something else that might be preventing your items from showing up? A custom DataTemplate or style that's not correct, perhaps?

Comment: @Jedediah Took me a while but then I saw it. It's the combo box's property that picks which field of the objects provided as the source to look into. I used a complex data type before and directed it towards the property *Cannonic* but with strings, it's not needed. Post your comment and mine as a combined reply so I can give you some reputation and accept the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a minor mistake in your xaml.

The `Binding` is a simple collection of string and not a POCO. There is no property called `Canonic` in the `List<string>` because of which you don't get your expected result